# Hidden Navigation bar (bottom bar with Home, Back and Overview button) is visible after showing a dialog or if the EditText gains focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog, android-fullscreen

There is a full screen activity with the following code blocks used to achieve the same:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// ….
}

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");

        super.onResume();
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

However, when a custom dialog is shown or if the edittext gains focus, the bottom navigation bar becomes visible and sticks around.
 The official doc says:

> If a new activity or dialog appears in the foreground, taking focus
>   and partially covering the activity in progress, the covered activity
>   loses focus and enters the Paused state. Then, the system calls
>   onPause() on it.
>
> When the covered activity returns to the foreground and regains focus,
>   it calls onResume().

But `onResume()` is not invoked when the dialog looses focus (checked with logs).

Also tried adding the following code in onCreate() of custom dialog:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

After adding the above code, the navigation bar hides when the custom dialog is in foreground, but when it goes out of focus, the navigation bar pops back onto the screen.

Also tried setting fullscreen mode using styles. Please refer below the same.

```
<style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

Same is the case with edittext. Activity starts up in fullscreen mode, but as soon as edittext gains focus, the bottom navigation bar is visible and sticks around.

Any input would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
fun View.setImmersiveMode() {
    isFocusableInTouchMode = false
    setOnClickListener {
        requestFocusFromTouch()
    }
}
editText.setImmersiveMode()
```